# Jump table in the beginning of disassembled binary

Tags: assembly, disassembly

Whenever I disassembly a binary file in Immunity Debugger, the first entry point is always a JMP to mainCRTStartup, which is fine...

But i'm curious about the cluster of other jumps that it is a part of. I was curious what this part is called?

For example;

```
003210EB   E9 A00E0000      JMP Hello_Wo._onexit
003210F0   E9 7B040000      JMP Hello_Wo.NtCurrentTeb
003210F5   E9 48280000      JMP Hello_Wo._HeapFree@12                ; JMP to kernel32.HeapFree
003210FA   E9 71080000      JMP Hello_Wo._RTC_SetErrorFunc
003210FF   E9 6C100000      JMP Hello_Wo._invoke_watson_if_error
00321104 > E9 F7070000      JMP Hello_Wo.mainCRTStartup
00321109   E9 C8270000      JMP Hello_Wo.___crtUnhandledException    ; JMP to MSVCR110.__crtUnhandledException
0032110E   E9 FD080000      JMP Hello_Wo.__CxxUnhandledExceptionFilt>
00321113   E9 78090000      JMP Hello_Wo.__CxxSetUnhandledExceptionF>
00321118   E9 CB270000      JMP Hello_Wo._QueryPerformanceCounter@4  ; JMP to kernel32.QueryPerformanceCounter
```

I just want to know what this is called, so I can read up on it. I tried searching for PE file structure, since I thought this might have been the import table, but they aren't exactly DLL entries, and they don't fit the offset in the PE header anyway.

I simply don't know what it is part of, so I don't know what to search for. Thank you.

Comment: I think this has something to do with relocations

Comment: To clarify - whenever your program calls functions from other libraries, it doesn't know the addresses of those functions when compiling to an object file (before linking). If several calls to the same function are made, rather than having a relocation for every instance of that call, the compiler adds a common "stub", which only requires one relocation. Any time the compiler sees a call to that function, it instead calls the "stub".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are jumps to the functions, imported from DLLs. As long as the real address of the imported function is not known, the compiled application calls the address from the jump table. This trick reduces the count of the addresses that need to be set during loading of the application.